# Django writing generic update view

Tags: django, class, view, updates

I'm trying to write a generic update view for my needs.
My view should update a field with the same name in different models. 
Check if the user has the permission, in a similar way to @permission_required decorator.
Should work on one object.
Works with ajax requests- means I need to return a code/json. 
I'm not using django built in forms, I write them myself.
For these reasons I could not use django built in UpdateView.
I thought of extending SingleObjectMixin. I got stuck on where I should save the model to the db.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyUpdateView(generic.UpdateView):
   ...

   def form_valid(self,form):
     # ... do something here ...
     obj = form.save()
     obj1 = AnotherModel.objects.get(...)
     obj1.the_field = obj.the_field
     obj1.save()
     obj2 = YetAnotherModel.objects.get(...)
     obj2.the_field = obj.the_field
     obj2.save()
     return super(MyUpdateView,self).form_valid()
```

Or, you can implement it in the form save method:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

   def save(self):

      obj = super(MyForm,self).save()
      # ... save to other models
      return obj
```

And then in your view:

```
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form.save()
```

Comment: It could be nice. But as I've said, I dont use django built in forms. So i cant extend updateview class.

Comment: If you just add some save behaviour, extending is the easiest way. But it really up to you, you have to save the form with 'form.save()' after 'form.is_valid()'. The extra saving code can run in the view, or the form save method. The CBV just handles it for you. Updated the answer.

Comment: I dont have any modelform/form classes at all. I manually code the forms in html. So i guess the form_valid method wont work. The question is if I can still use updateview or create something similar,  and to implement what form.save() do by myself. I'm  not sure what classes I should extend.

Comment: I think that you miss something in django core architecture. Forms are the python classes that handle the HTML and the user input. Of course, you can write your own, but why?

Comment: I know that is possible to write forms as python classes. But I choose not to for some reasons - my forms invole with some heavy javascript which is hard to maintain when the form is it seperate py file. I didnt like that I have to write the "id" attribute in the form class that I refer in javascript code.

Comment: Anyway, the point is: how can I implement a similar class based view like update/create views, even though I dont use form class. So I handle them with requset.POST['fieldname']

Comment: You want to do it as an exercise?

Comment: No, I do need it for a web app. Many forms are already written and more I write this day, I just thought if I could improve my form handling server side. Today it is just request.POST['field'] in a view function, as I've said.

Comment: So maybe you want to subclass django Form,   add some bridging code, and use this class as the webapp form